# Como implementar ng-show en un auto-completar de angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material

Hola a todos tengo este autocompletar de material y quiero conseguir que al seleccionar un item se muestre mi etiqueta `<p>`:

```
<div class="resumen" ng-cloak>     
    <md-autocomplete    
            md-selected-item="selectedItem"   
            md-selected-text="selectedItem"   
            md-search-text="searchText"  
            md-items="item in querySearch(searchText)"  
            md-item-text="item.rut"  
            placeholder="Ingrese rut del paciente">  
        <md-not-found>Rut no encontrado.</md-not-found>  
        <md-icon md-svg-icon="images/buscame.svg"></md-icon>    

        <span md-highlight-text="searchText">{{item.rut + ' Numero: '+item.numero}}</span>   
    </md-autocomplete>     

    <p style="padding-top:20px; font-size:18px;" ng-show="  {{!selectedItem.rut === undefined}}">
        {{'El rut seleciado es: ' +selectedItem.rut+' y su numero de atención: ' + selectedItem.numero}}
    </p>

</div>
```

Como puedo implementar correctarmente en esta situacion un `ng-hide`, `ng-show` hasta pense en un `ng-change` pero me la gano... saludos....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta expresión

```
ng-show="{{!selectedItem.rut === undefined}}"
```

Debería ser

```
ng-show="!!selectedItem.rut"
```

o

```
ng-show="selectedItem.rut"
```

Esta directiva está diseñada para usar una expresión, no una interpolación `{{}}` como la tienes actualmente.

Además no es necesario comparar contra `undefined`, puedes usar [truthy](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/) y simplificar la expresión usando `!!` para coercionar a booleano o usar el valor directamente ya que si tiene algo la expresión evaluará a `true`. Recuerda que lo que quieres es mostrar el valor si hay algo ahí.

Comment: Gracias amigo, me sirvio.